# Mysql Many-to-many (AND Where) select

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, entity-attribute-value

i have this database setup:

- products

  - id
  - [fields...]
- tags

  - id
  - [fields...]
- product_tag

  - id
  - product_id
  - tag_id

If have this records in my database

- Products

  - Product A [id: 1]
  - Product B [id: 2]
  - Product C [id: 3]

---

- Tags

  - Tag A [id: 1]
  - Tag B [id: 2]
  - Tag C [id: 3]

---

- Produc_Tag

  - [product_id: 1, tag_id: 1]
  - [product_id: 1, tag_id: 2]
  - [product_id: 2, tag_id: 1]
  - [product_id: 2, tag_id: 3]
  - [product_id: 3, tag_id: 1]
  - [product_id: 3, tag_id: 2]

---

How do i query to get the products that have tag_id 1 AND 2 (it must by products with tag_id 1 AND 2)
in this example: "Product A" and "Product C"

Comment: What is EAV about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT P.id
FROM products P
INNER JOIN products_tags PT ON PT.product_id = P.id
WHERE PT.tag_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY P.id
HAVING COUNT(PT.*) = 2
```

Comment: @Neto [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14572767) to your answer which got rejected by the reviewers. You may wish to consider improving it yourself.

Comment: I did get the table name wrong, but I think OP should change his table name. Looks more correct this way.

Comment: Do you happen to know anything about the " MariaDB doesn't accept `COUNT(PT.*)`" issue?

Comment: Been a while since I used Maria and I don't remember that, but if the `*` is a problem, you could change it to `PT.tag_id`

Comment: I don't know, I was mostly interested in the correctness of the edit suggestion that I tried to approve earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM product_tag
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) = '1,2'
)
```

Comment: hmm... This might just be better than mine

Comment: I don't know if the order of the tag IDs is guaranteed to be `'1,2'`.